# Summing data in google sheets based on multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets-query

I have an export from a time sheet program of hours worked on projects in the following format.

### Existing Data

```
Resource | Project | Subtask | Hours

Alice    | Artemis | Dev     | 10 
Alice    | Artemis | Dev     | 20 
Alice    | Artemis | Dev     | 30 
Alice    | Boreas  | Dev     | 10 
Beth     | Artemis | Test    | 10 
Beth     | Boreas  | Test    | 20 
Beth     | Boreas  | Test    | 30 
Beth     | Boreas  | Test    | 10 
Claire   | Boreas  | Dev     | 10 
Claire   | Boreas  | Dev     | 20 
Claire   | Boreas  | Dev     | 30 
Claire   | Boreas  | Dev     | 10
```

Can anyone tell me how to generate the following summary/ aggregation report? I assume the answer will involve Query, but I haven't been able to get the summing of the hours to work, and I wonder if the answer will require a combination of query and other functions.

### Desired Output

```
Project | Subtask | Resource | Total Hours

Artemis | Dev     | Alice    | 60 
Artemis | Test    | Beth     | 10 
Boreas  | Dev     | Alice    | 10 
Boreas  | Dev     | Claire   | 70 
Boreas  | Test    | Beth     | 60
```

---

Thanks in advance for any suggestions that move me forward.

Answer (score 0):

Looks similar to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100274/google-sheets-query-group-by-multiple

Does something like this work?:

```
QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE(
<spreadsheet_url>,
<range>")),
"Select Project, Subtask, Resource, sum(Hours)
group by Project, Subtask, Resource label sum(Hours) 'Total Hours'")
```